# BigQuery joining and filling gaps

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I have the following data sets I want to merge, but I am trying to fill in empty rows.

```
WITH data1 as (
  SELECT "2021-01-01" date, 'abc' company, 3 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-02" date, 'abc' company, 4 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-06" date, 'abc' company, 17 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-02" date , 'xzy' company, 2 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-04" date , 'xzy' company, 16 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-08" date , 'xzy' company, 16 cumulative_count
),

data_dates as (
    # SELECT * 
    # FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-01-01', '2021-01-08',INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS date
    SELECT "2021-01-01" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-02" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-03" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-04" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-05" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-06" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-07" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-08" date
)

SELECT 
  a.date,
  b.company,
  b.cumulative_count
FROM data_dates as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN data1 as b
ON a.date = b.date
```

Resulting in

[image]

How would I go about replicating the results for row 2021-01-03 from 2021-01-02 for both companies. Basically filling in the empty rows until new updated values come into play.
Also how would I specify to get company xzy for 2021-01-01.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should do

```
WITH data1 as (
  SELECT "2021-01-01" date, 'abc' company, 3 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-02" date, 'abc' company, 4 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-06" date, 'abc' company, 17 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-02" date , 'xzy' company, 2 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-04" date , 'xzy' company, 16 cumulative_count UNION ALL
  SELECT "2021-01-08" date , 'xzy' company, 16 cumulative_count
), data_dates as (
    # SELECT * 
    # FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-01-01', '2021-01-08',INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS date
    SELECT "2021-01-01" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-02" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-03" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-04" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-05" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-06" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-07" date UNION ALL
    SELECT "2021-01-08" date
), data_companies as (
    SELECT DISTINCT company
    FROM data1
) 
SELECT 
  a.date,
  c.company,
  IFNULL(cumulative_count, LAST_VALUE(cumulative_count IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY c.company ORDER BY a.date)) cumulative_count      
FROM data_dates as a, data_companies as c
LEFT JOIN data1 as b
ON a.date = b.date 
AND c.company = b.company
ORDER BY date, company
```

with output

[image]